# ES6 clon array that is inside an object

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have an object `state` with a key `shoppingCart`, that contains an array. I know **ES6** way to clone an array is `let newArray = [...originalArray]`, but I can't find a way to clone the array in `state.shoppingCart`. I tried `let newShoppingCart = [...state.shoppingCart]`, but I get a syntax error.

Comment: `let newShoppingCart = state.shoppingCart.slice()` will work just fine.  There's no requirement to use fancy new language features when long running features work just fine.

Comment: `let newShoppingCart = [...state.shoppingCart]` is not a syntax error.

Comment: What does the syntax error say?